# How to use variables?

Tags: vimrc, variables

I'm trying to use indent size as variable, but it doesn't work.

```
let indent=4
set tabstop=&indent
set softtabstop=&indent
set shiftwidth=&indent
set expandtab
```

I tried both `&indent` and `%(&indent)` - just guessing, but it still broken.

Comment: @jamessan Hmm. No, it doesn't look as duplicate (or similar) from my point of view.

Comment: They're both asking how to use variables for `set` commands.  Although you're trying to modify a different option, the mechanism is the same.

Comment: James, welcome to [vi.se]! Consider taking the [tour] to get acclimated with the site. As things currently stand, I agree with @jamessan that your question is a duplicate of the other. Could you possible [edit] and clarify how it is different, or doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: They may both be asking how to use variables for set commands, but I can't get it to work following those instructions either. Specifically, every attempt returns `E521: Number required after =: tabstop=$indent`, which appears to not be a check that would be done for options not requiring a number.

Comment: `:let &tabstop=indent` `$` is used for environment variables. `&` is for settings. You don't need either for vimscript variables.

Comment: I try that and there's no error but no effect - tabstop remains 8, while indent is set to 4.  Oddly enough, I feel a little relieved at that, because I spent over 20 minutes trying to put an edit into the post showing the testing that I've done at least, and my version information and it'd be really disheartening to know that there was an answer out here waiting for half the time I was working on that. Although, on the other hand, there would be an answer which would be nice.

Comment: Ok, update: that did work - but :set tabstop? did not update its value until I actually tested how it worked, which seems really weird. And with that, thank you and g'night.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. I can't reproduce that behavior. Checking the `let &xxx=...` with a `set xxx?` immediately after shows expected value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most is already in the comments, but to summarize:

```
let indent=4
let &tabstop=indent
let &softtabstop=indent
let &shiftwidth=indent
set expandtab
```

If you want to set a setting (like `tabstop`) to the value of a variable, you have to Vim script expressions instead of set-expressions. In that case, settings are given with a leading `&`. `indent` is a Vim script variable so NO `&` is needed.

See it as namespaces. The leading `&` tells that the following name is from the namespace "Vim settings". Like a leading `$` tells, that the following name is from the namespace "environment variables".

So the following two lines leads to identical results.

```
set tabstop=4
let &tabstop=4
```

You could also do:

```
set tabstop=4
let &softtabstop=&tabstop
let &shiftwidth=&tabstop
set expandtab
```

Another way to achieve the same (also NOT recommended in this scenario) is:

```
let indent=4
execute "set tabstop=" . indent
execute "set softtabstop=" . indent
execute "set shiftwidth=" . indent
set expandtab
```

Comment: how can i bind a command like "let indent=4" with some keys, basically i want to bind the command "let &lines=line("$")+4" to some binding.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have all tabstop related settings follow each other, it is best to use:

```
set tabstop=4      " set to specific value here, that you want to use
set shiftwidth=0   " follow tabstop setting
set softtabstop=-1 " follow shiftwidth setting
```

That will also work for the vartabfeature (since patch 8.1.542).

Comment: Upvoted, but it was required to choose only one answer to accept, and I choose the one which was more detailed.